# Update a new entity before committing with _unitOfWorkManager

Tags: c#, entity-framework, unit-of-work, aspnetboilerplate, change-tracking

Within my service (`class MyService : AbpServiceBase`), I am trying to do the following:

- Insert an entity into SQL and retrieve the Id
- Make a REST call to an external system and retrieve that systemId
- Update a field in the original entity with the systemId

The error I get:

> Database operation expected to affect 1 row(s) but actually affected 0 row(s)

```
[UnitOfWork(isTransactional: false)]
public async Task<Guid> CreateAsync(InfoDto myInfo)
{
    int? tenantId = _unitOfWorkManager.Current.GetTenantId();
    objInfo = await _infoRepository.InsertAsync(myInfo);
    newObjId = CreateNewIdentifier(tenantId);

    objInfo.ExternalIdentifier = newObjId;
    await _infoRepository.UpdateAsync(objInfo);
    return objInfo.Id;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is always so simple once you know the answer... All that was required is an annotation. Hope others benefit from this too.

[UnitOfWork(IsDisabled = true)]

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the `UpdateAsync`. `objInfo` is already tracked.

```cs
[UnitOfWork(isTransactional: false)]
public async Task<Guid> CreateAsync(InfoDto myInfo)
{
    int? tenantId = _unitOfWorkManager.Current.GetTenantId();
    objInfo = await _infoRepository.InsertAsync(myInfo);
    newObjId = CreateNewIdentifier(tenantId);

    objInfo.ExternalIdentifier = newObjId;
    // await _infoRepository.UpdateAsync(objInfo); // Remove this
    return objInfo.Id;
}
```